# Можно ли объявлять асинхронными функции, которые возвращают Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Например возьмем модуль `request` (его `callback`, не `promise` версию) и напишем такой код:

```js
const request = require('request');
async function google(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
          if(error) reject(error); 
          resolve(body);
        });
    });
}
```

Данная функция объявлена как `async` что значит она возвращает `Promise` в любом случае, в ней мы делаем `return` другого `Promise`, сути это в принципе не меняет, но встает несколько вопросов:

1. Стоит ли так делать?
2. Это говнокод?
3. Почему стоит или не стоит так делать?
4. Как это влияет на прожорливость и скорость?

Comment: Кажется нет смысла тут асинк делать. Единственный смысл объявить функцию как асинк, это чтоб заюзать внутри await. А await мы используем как раз, чтобы подождать, пока испольнится промис. Так что, нет, не стоит. Нет, не говнокод. Почему не стоит описал выше. Никак не влияет.

Comment: Ну на счет `await` это да, в данном случае будет актуально `async`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меня довольно давно интересоавл этот вопрос и я пытался найти ответы в официальной документации но либо я плохо ищу либо там нет такой информации. Если кто в курсе, поделитесь пожалуйста ссылкой в комментарии.

Тем не менее я нашел способ проверить эффективность данного подхода и как оказалось использование ключевого слова `async` и явное создание `Promise` объекта посредством выражения `new Promise(...)` внутри функции является не эффективным и вот почему.

На основе примера "[Почему использовать return await плохая идея](https://medium.com/@kanby/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-return-await-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F-e87b70015f0c)" я создал тестовый файл и проверил выполнение кода таким образом:

```js
// promise-hooks.js
const hooks = require("async_hooks");
const fs = require("fs");

let indent = 0;

module.exports = hooks.createHook({
  promiseResolve(asyncId) {
    const indentStr = " ".repeat(indent);
    fs.writeSync(1, `${indentStr}resolved: ${asyncId}\n`);
  },
  init(asyncId, type, triggerAsyncId, resource) {
    const eid = hooks.executionAsyncId();
    const indentStr = " ".repeat(indent);
    const dt1 = `${indentStr}${type}(${asyncId})`;
    const dt2 = `trigger: ${triggerAsyncId}`;
    const dt3 = `resource: ${resource.parentId}`;
    const dt4 = `execution: ${eid}`;

    fs.writeSync(1, `${dt1}, ${dt2}, ${dt3}, ${dt4}\n`);
  },
  before(asyncId) {
    const indentStr = " ".repeat(indent);
    fs.writeSync(1, `${indentStr}before:  ${asyncId}\n`);
    indent += 2;
  },
  after(asyncId) {
    indent -= 2;
    const indentStr = " ".repeat(indent);
    fs.writeSync(1, `${indentStr}after:   ${asyncId}\n`);
  },
  destroy(asyncId) {
    const indentStr = " ".repeat(indent);
    fs.writeSync(1, `${indentStr}destroy: ${asyncId}\n`);
  },
});
```

Тестовый код (без использования `async`)

```js
const hooks = require("./promise-hooks.js");
hooks.enable();

function asyncTest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve());
}

asyncTest();
```

Результат выполнения:

```sh
PROMISE(2), trigger: 1, resource: undefined, execution: 1
resolved: 2
```

Теперь обявляем асинхронную функцию с помощью `async`

```js
const hooks = require("./promise-hooks.js");
hooks.enable();

async function asyncTest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve());
}

asyncTest();
```

Результат выполнения:

```sh
PROMISE(2), trigger: 1, resource: undefined, execution: 1
PROMISE(3), trigger: 1, resource: undefined, execution: 1
resolved: 3
resolved: 2
before:  2
  PROMISE(4), trigger: 3, resource: undefined, execution: 2
after:   2
before:  4
  resolved: 2
  resolved: 4
after:   4
```

Как видим из примера в результате получаем два `Promise-объекта`, похоже ключевое слово `async` неявно оборачивает возвращаемый результат функции в Promise, что по сути является неэффективным. Поэтому в случае явного использования `new Promise()`, ключевое слово `async` лучше не использовать и наоборот.